# SQL OPENJSON Array in Objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2022

I have a table with the following structure/rows:

| ID | OptionName | OptionValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Gender | Male |
| 1 | Gender | Female |

I want to query the database and return the following JSON:

```
[{
    "OptionName":"Gender",
    "Values":[
        "Male",
        "Female"
    ]
}]
```

However the result I'm currently getting is this:

```
[{
    "OptionName":"Gender",
    "Values":[
        {
            "OptionValue":"Male"
        },
        {
            "OptionValue":"Female"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) OptionName,
(
    JSON_QUERY(
        (
            SELECT OptionValue 
            FROM [TestJSON].[dbo].[Options] 
            WHERE OptionName = 'Gender' 
            FOR JSON PATH
        )
    )
) AS [Values]
FROM [TestJSON].[dbo].[Options]
WHERE OptionName = 'Gender'
FOR JSON PATH
```

What can I do to get the result I need?

Comment: T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Answer (score 1):

Although SQL Server 2022 introduced `JSON_ARRAY()` function, it's difficult to use it to build a JSON array with variable items count, so you may try a string based approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.OptionName, JSON_QUERY(a.[Values]) AS [Values]
FROM Options o
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', OptionValue, '"'), ','), ']') 
   FROM Options
   WHERE OptionName = o.OptionName
) a ([Values]) 
--WHERE o.OptionName = 'Gender'
FOR JSON PATH
```

If you know the maximum number of values for each option (`5` in the example), a combination of `JSON_ARRAY()` and `PIVOT` relational operator is another option:

```
SELECT OptionName, JSON_ARRAY([1], [2], [3], [4], [5]) AS [Values]
FROM (  
   SELECT OptionName, OptionValue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OptionName ORDER BY ID) AS Rn
   FROM Options
) t
PIVOT (MAX(OptionValue) FOR Rn IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) p
FOR JSON PATH
```